# Jquery post loop through json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to loop through my data I received when doing a jquery .post however it's showing up as a much higher count than it is. What is making it say 109 as the length of data?

```
.done(function( data ) {
   console.log(data);
   console.log(data.length);
});
```

Below is the console logs:

```
[{"lat":33.115868,"lng":-117.186295},{"lat":33.117237,"lng":-117.186295},{"lat":33.111866,"lng":-117.186295}]

109
```

Comment: currently you're reading the length of `json string`. specify the data type as `json`, then jquery will parse the `json string` and return javascript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, it looks like JSON, the data received from server is string. To convert it into JSON use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before iterating over it.

Use

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

to get JSON object from the string.

---

*OR* use `dataType: 'json'` in [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) configuration.

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the encoded data using:`JSON.parse` or `$.parseJSON`.

```
var ndata=JSON.parse(data);
console.log(ndata.length);
```